# Converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure spGetDetails, Line 88
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I have already converted this `@mfr_id` to int type then also getting the above error.

I'm getting error while executing stored procedure.

The line which I'm getting error is:

```
if(@mfr_id = 5)
```

Comment: What is the `@mfr_id` variable declared as?

Comment: @OMG Ponies "@mfr_id is varchar but its storing 1 2, 3, 4." From comments to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if(@mfr_id = '5')
```

Value comparisons have to be the same data type, or there has to be implicit data type conversion.  Explicit conversion -- which is when you use [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) -- is ideal for maintenance because the operation is obvious.

Depending on your needs, the [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehs9h2x9%28VS.85%29.aspx) function might help.  And be careful to define a length to your [n]varchar variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

So it seems that @mfr_id is a varchar. To avoid the syntactic issue use the answer in OMG Ponies post.

But you also say that it is storing the string "1 2, 3, 4.....". So semantically are you wanting the IF statement to be true if it contains the value '5'?

If so you might need something like this

```
set @mfr_id = REPLACE(@mfr_id, ' ','')
if ((@mfr_id LIKE '5,%') OR (@mfr_id LIKE '%,5,%') OR (@mfr_id LIKE '%,5'))
```

**Original Answer - Obsolete**

```
if(CONVERT(int, @mfr_id) = 5)
```

should do the trick hopefully. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for details. Although actually I think it should be implicitly converted. What is the value of @mfr_id? It should tell you this in the error message I think.

Comment: Ah in that case make the other side of the expression a string with if(@mfr_id = '5'). Can I just check that you need equality and you aren't trying to do a "contains" type check?

Comment: if the value of @mfr_id is not numeric this will fail, try: `declare @mfr_id varchar(5);set @mfr_id='A';if(CONVERT(int, @mfr_id) = 5) PRINT 'WILL get an error!'`

Comment: Yes I was waiting for the OP to get back to me before updating my answer to reflect the comments. I'll do it now.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is written using Oracle's PL/SQL syntax and one of the Oracle regular expression routines.  I don't know T-SQL well enough to transcribe it but I expect that similar capabilities are available:

```
FOR aRow IN
  (WITH DATA AS (SELECT @mfg_id AS S FROM DUAL)
     SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(S, '[^ ,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS NUM_STRING
       FROM DATA
       CONNECT BY LEVEL < LENGTH(S) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(S, '[ ,]', '')))
LOOP
  IF aRow.NUM_STRING = '5' THEN
    NULL;  -- do something appropriate here
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Share and enjoy.